# cannot detect when user reached the end of a browser on phones

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check when user reach the bottom of browser and I use the following:

```
 var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
        alert();
    }
```

When I test it on desktop and also chrome emulator it works fine but on real phone(both android and IOS) it does not work.

Is there any better way to detect the end of scrolls on phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        alert("you're at the bottom of the page");
    }
};
```

Comment: Awesome worked. Can explain it. I am always confused with this